# Mechanics question - ladder leaning against a wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, statics, equilibrium

I am struggling with part a) of this question:

[image: question]

Here is the solution:

[image: solution to question.]

In part a) they prove that $F \leq \mu R$ is false for this system. So as $F$ is neither less than nor equal to $\mu R$ it can only be greater than $\mu R$. I don't understand this. My understanding of friction is that the friction, $F$, can only increase up to the value of $\mu R$, it can't increase past this value. Whilst $F$ is increasing up to and equaling the value of $\mu R$ the system is in equilibrium. Then, after this point $F = \mu R$ but the opposing force overcomes this frictional force (i.e. "pushing force" $> \mu R$) and so the object moves and the system is no longer in equilibrium.

Is my understanding not correct? Can friction be greater than $\mu R$?

If this solution is incorrect could someone please tell me what's happening? I'm fairly confused at the moment.

Comment: Why do you say "So as $F$ if neither less than nor equal to $\mu R$ ... "?  The discovery that $F \leq \mu R$ says exactly the opposite.  By the way, what is that notation with the arrows?  I've never seen it before.  What does it mean?

Comment: This seems an appropriate homework question to me. Effort is shown, and the question has a conceptual tone: correctly interpreting an inequality.

Comment: @garyp I think the answer to this question explains it better than I could - I was simply misunderstanding what the inequality implied. And $R(\rightarrow)$ means "resolving horizontally", it's the same idea for resolving vertically. Only I think in the solution they got their arrows confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget friction, and put a brick there. What is the force $F$ required to keep the ladder from sliding? $F=\frac{3}{8}W$ from the solution.

Now, take out the brick and see of friction can provide the same force. The maximum traction is $F_{f} = \mu R = \frac{3}{10} W$.

Since $F>F_f$ the required force IS MORE then the available friction force (max. traction) then the ladder will slip.

Maybe the wording in the question is a little weird, but the gist is to compare the required force for static equilibrium with the available force from friction.